# Missing RichTextBox in VS2010 / Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, richtextbox

I'm banging my head here...

I do not have the RichTextBox control in my Silverlight toolbox.  I've tried to add it via AddItems and even though it's checked and the toolbox window seems to refresh (expands or flickers), the RichTextBox does not appear.

I've tried just adding it to the XAML directly but it won't work.  I've also just tried to programmatically add it in the code behind.  Again, it appears not to exist.  I downloaded and installed the Silverlight ToolKit again but it's still not showing up.

I've tried adding it from Silverlight Controls, WPF Controls, and Windows Controls in the AddItems box.  It's listed as an option but it just won't show up.

Am I bugged?

UPDATE:  I tried "Show All" in the toolbox contextual menu and I can now see it but it's greyed out and I can't add it to my project.  ???

UPDATE 2:  If I create a new Silverlight project the RichTextBox is there and usable.  Same references and everything.

SOLVED MYSELF:  I just ended up making a new project and copying over the App.xaml and MainPage.xaml.  They I rewired the .aspx test page to point to the new project.  Everything works and - as far as I know - nothing changed.  What the hell?  Thanks StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to add this to your original project, check in the silverlight project properties that it is targeting Silverlight 4 not 3.